# Baffled by simple many-to-one association issue

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm following the [Entity Relationships/Associations example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) on the Symfony website and cannot seem to get associations working.

In this example, the `Product` has a `Category`, but the `Category` has no `Products`. (EDIT) UNLESS I specifically associate the Product to the Category AND the Category to the Product. According to the documentation, this association should be implied.

I've created the Category class:

```
class Category
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="category")
     */
    protected $products;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

And the product class:

```
class Product
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $category;
}
```

Here is my code to test associations:

```
public function simpleTestAction()
{
    $category = new Category();
    $category->setName('Main Products');

    $product = new Product();
    $product->setName('Foo');

    // relate this product to the category
    $product->setCategory($category);

    // EDIT: also relate the category to the product.
    // WHY does this fix the problem? WHY is this necessary?
    // associating both the Category to the Product AND
    // Product to the Category is required.
    // Uncomment the line below, and this will work.

    // $category->addProduct($product);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($category);
    $em->persist($product);
    $em->flush();

    $categoryId = $category->getId();
    $productId = $product->getId();

    print_r('Created product id: '.$productId.' and category id: '.$categoryId);

    // re-fetch the product to test
    $product = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')
        ->find($productId);

    // prove that the product exists.
    print_r("\n\nFetched product: " . $product->getId());

    // fetch the category directly from the product
    $category = $product->getCategory();

    // prove that the product has a category.
    print_r("\nCategory name: " . $product->getCategory()->getName()); 

    // get the products from the category.
    // this should have at least one product, since we got the category
    // object directly from the product.
    $products = $category->getProducts();

    // prove we have a category
    print_r("\n\nFetched category: " . $category->getId());

    // issue: there are NO PRODUCTS belonging to this category,
    // even though the source product has this category.
    print_r("\nCount of products: " . count($products));

    die();
}
```

Here is the output. As you can see, the `Product` has a `Category`, but the `Category` has no `Products`:

```
Created product id: 1 and category id: 1

Fetched product: 1
Category name: Main Products

Fetched category: 1
Count of products: 0
```

Here is the output after the reciprocal `$category->addProduct($product);` line is uncommented:

```
Created product id: 1 and category id: 1

Fetched product: 1
Category name: Main Products

Fetched category: 1
Count of products: 1
```

I am using Symfony 2.3.7 and have cleared caches several times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would also need to add the product to the category either in your controller like so..

```
$category->addProduct($product)
```

or you could add the category setter in the addProduct setter in the category like so...

```
public function addProduct(Product $product)
{
    $this->products->add($product);
    $product->setCategory($this);

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Even though the inverse functions do not appear to be necessary according to the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/book/doctrine.html#saving-related-entities), your solution does solve the problem. Can you tell me why this is necessary? I'll up-vote this solution and mark as answered in a day or two, but I would love to know the reasons behind the need to add the `Category` to the `Product` AND the `Product` to the `Category` since there is only one foreign key.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure to be honest. From memory I think that if you didn't do the above then it would still work correctly (find the connected product from the category) on the next page load. From that I assume that some thinking is done when the manager is created on page load but then that could end up being a massive operation if you had a huge database so I'm probably wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure either, but it looks like if you use the same instance of a manager in the same function on multiple entities, you need to set both sides of the association. Doctrine does some work, but not that much. As you said, that could mean a massive operation. Unfortunately, this is not clear in the [Association Updates section of the Doctrine Docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#important-concepts).